# Google Plus Sign in allowed for Google Apps users when Plus is disabled

Tags: google-plus, google-apps

If I am a new user in gmail and I am using Google+ sign in, it will ask me to create a Google+ account.

If I am a new user in Google Apps and Google+ is disabled in my Google Apps domain, I can still login via Google+ and I am not asked to create an account.  If I go to plus.google.com it shows Google+ is disabled.  Shouldn't it follow that if Google+ is disabled in Google Apps that the user should not be able to login?

Answer (score 0):

No. Google has specifically upgraded the Sign-In API to support all Google account types. You can [read about it](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html) on their blog.

Comment: Just kind of a confusing experience if you are a Google Apps user and unaware that your admin has disabled it.  Then you've used plus to sign in but you don't have actually a plus account - so what account is used to sign in?

Comment: Just think of it as they sign in with their Google account and sometimes there is a Google+ profile component to that account and sometimes there isn't.